# How to monitor ESXi in zabbix

Tags: web-services, wsdl, zabbix, esxi

I have an ESXi which contains some VMs. I want to use the built in template 'Template Virt VMware' in zabbix to discover all VMs and their related Items, but I don't know what should I write for {$URL} in MACROS!!
I googled and found that I should write the webservice SDK url. But what is the correct url?
I use the following:

https://serverip/sdk/vimService.wsdl in which 'serverip' is the ip of the ESXi but it didn't work!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what "but it didn't work" actually means. Also, did you specify a valid username and password, too?

Comment: I mean zabbix cannot discover VMs and their related Items by providing https://serverip/sdk/vimService.wsdl as the {$URL} and root as the {$USERNAME} and root's password as {$PASSWORD}. I used the username and password which is used for ssh login. How can I check whether the url is correct or not? Can I test it with soap client plugin on mozilla firefox?

Comment: One more thing, I forgot to enable  StartVMwareCollectors. I set it to 2. but after restarting zabbix server I got the following error in the log file: error reason for "testesxi-192.168.50.32:vmware.hv.discovery[{$URL}]" changed: Cannot get EventHistoryCollector session

Comment: Zabbix does not use ssh for VMware monitoring, you have to use VMware credentials.

Comment: Yeah I know. I think I could get information from vCenter inside Zabbix. the right url is like this : https://<vCenter_ipaddress>/sdk with the username and password which is used to connect to the vCenter server via vsphere client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/vm_monitoring) you can't monitor vms on the server using this method.

In this method you should enter `https://esxi-server-ip/sdk` for `{$URL}`

[image]

It will manitor your esxi host it self, for manitoring the virtual machines, you should to install `zabbix agent` on them or use something like `snmp` or `ipmi` for each of them